# Sync-AzureAnalysisServicesInstance causing issues in syncing scaled out Azure Analysis Service Instances

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-analysis-services

I have been trying to sync my scaled out Azure Analysis Instance using the command Sync-AzureAnalysisServicesInstance, however when I use it, it suggests to login first "Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount" cmdlet.

I am not able to get around this cmdlet and have been error like:
"Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount : AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Client assertion contains an 
invalid signature. [Reason - The key was not found., Thumbprint of key used by client: "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"

The code snippet is below:

```html
    workflow ScaleOut
{

    $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

     "Logging in to Azure..."
      Add-AzureRmAccount `
       -ServicePrincipal `
       -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
       -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
       -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint     

     Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "aaa-bbb12-ccc"
     Set-AzureRmAnalysisServicesServer -Name "aasprakhar" -ResourceGroupName "Storage" -ReadonlyReplicaCount "1" -Administrator "SA@abcdehotmail.onmicrosoft.com"

InlineScript { 
$ApplicationCredential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "SA"  
Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount -RolloutEnvironment "asazure://westeurope.asazure.windows.net/abcde" -ServicePrincipal  -TenantId "asf-asdf-asdcv" -ApplicationId "aaa-bb-ccc" -CertificateThumbprint "xxx-xxx-xxxx"

#Sync-AzureAnalysisServicesInstance -Instance "asazure://westeurope.asazure.windows.net/aasprakhar" -Database "adventureworks" -PassThru 

}
```

```
Can anyone please suggest what am I doing wrong here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All. I was able to figure it out. Following is the code snippet for adding the account to login to AS Instance:

```html
workflow ScaleOut
{

    $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

     "Logging in to Azure..."
      Add-AzureRmAccount `
       -ServicePrincipal `
       -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
       -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
       -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint     

     Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "xxx-xxx-xxx"
     Set-AzureRmAnalysisServicesServer -Name "abcde" -ResourceGroupName "xxxx" 

InlineScript { 
$ApplicationCredential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "SA"  

Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount -RolloutEnvironment: westeurope.asazure.windows.net -Credential: $ApplicationCredential

# Sync-AzureAnalysisServicesInstance -Instance asazure://westeurope.asazure.windows.net/xxxx -Database adventureworks -PassThru 

}

}
```